# How to affix a div some offset from the screen top on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-2, affix

I want to affix a div not at the screen top but some offset from the screen top.
For example, the html looks like

```
<ul class='.sticky-header'>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  ..
</ul>
```

And the sticky header element is affixed at top using javascript below:

```
$('.sticky-header').affix({
    offset: {
             top: $('.sticky-header').offset().top
            }
 });
```

The above code affixes the ul element at the screen top on scrolling past the offset specified. But I need the div to be affixed not at the screen top but say 30px from the screen top. Is it possible?

Comment: did you try adding 30px in top?

Comment: @Yogesh Offset is to specify the position past which the div should be affixed top. But my requirement is different.

Comment: <ul class='.sticky-header'> ... note the '.' and the single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it via css like below

```
.sticky-header.affix{
    top:30px;
 }
```

So when it gets fixed to the top, it is always 30px below the screen's top which is 0px.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have added class with (.) remove . from below markup

Expected code

```
   <ul class='sticky-header'>
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>bb</li>
  </ul>
```

and try, it will work.